# Does Ubuntu 14.04 have its own 'Task Manager'?

Tags: 14.04

Does Ubuntu 14.04 have its own 'Task Manager'? Like the one in Windows, where you would check what program is using how much and such.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `top`.
Just open a terminal enter `top` command and it will show you which process is consuming how much **Memory** and **CPU**. Visit the link it will really help you
[12-Top-commands](http://www.tecmint.com/12-top-command-examples-in-linux/)

Answer (score 2):

Open 'System Monitor' application ; it's very similar to task manager in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about the Task Manager in Windows is that you can use a keyboard shortcut to bring it up, even if the computer is frozen.

The System Monitor in Ubuntu is accessible from the Dash: click on the Dash and type “System” and it should come up. This, however, is fairly slow: it involves the graphics-heavy Dash and a search through installed programs and files.

As [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/886852) points out, it may be quicker (and more portable to different versions of Ubuntu), to open the System Monitor from the terminal: just type the command `gnome-system-monitor`. (The Terminal itself can be opened from the Dash, or by the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.)

However, the best option is to [create a new keyboard shortcut](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html). This option is available from System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Custom Shortcuts. You’ll want to create a new shortcut with the name `System Monitor` and the command `gnome-system-monitor`. The key combination you choose is up to you (I went with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>). Now you’ll be able to launch the System Monitor even when the computer is freezing.

Answer (score 0):

use the following command

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

if  not found then run

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor
```

Comment: `gnome-system-monitor` is the name of the package of the "System Monitor" application mentioned in one of the earlier answers. It would be better to suggest a change to it (via the "edit" link below it) instead of posting a separate answer about the same thing.